# It's the weight! How to return weighted probabilities? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax

Needing to write a function that returns a number between 0 and 6 (inclusive)with the following probabilities:

```
0: 10%, 1: 26%, 2: 33%, 3: 18%, 4: 9%, 5: 3%, 6: 1%
```

While this is likely best done with objects, I'm not that far along... so think I need to iterate over 2 arrays (say `var values=[ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `var weights=[10, 26, etc]`

My ridiculous question: in arrays: how do I return `values[i]` a `[weighted]` number of times .... all my syntax efforts return the two values multiplied (basically `values[i] * weighted[i]`).

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want a random number between 0 and 6 weighted as you specified? Please share your attempts with us.

Comment: correct. first I tried doing this without iteration as follows (but didn't get it right).
In a test set,  I tried the following, but it multiplies each [i] with the value, instead of returning that "n" of [i] 
    var a = [1,2,3];
var b= [3,2,1];
var myArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    myArr.push(a[i] * b[i]);
}
console.log(myArr);

(output [3, 4, 3])
what I'm hoping to output is:
[1,1,1,2,2, 3]